# ASP.NET MVC 404 not found error in prod but not in test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 website. I have been trying to add a link to a sitemap for it in the lower right-hand corner. The link is implemented in _Layout.cshtml using:

```
<p class="notep right">@Html.ActionLink("Site Map", "SiteMap", "Home")</p>
```

I see the web page appear beautifully on my local machine. But when I put it on the server I get:

## Server Error in '/' Application.

### *The resource cannot be found.*

**Description:** HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

**Requested URL:** /Home/SiteMap

I had this problem initially on my local machine as well. But there I fixed it by adding the code block:

```
public ActionResult SiteMap()
{
    return View();
}
```

to the HomeController.

I can confirm that this change uploaded successfully to the website as well.

All the other action links on the website work perfectly. And so does this one on my local machine. So what might be different about the production environment that would prevent it from working correctly there?

EDIT

My RouteConfig file is:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] {"MyNamespace.Controllers"}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

My project type from my csproj file is:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

I certainly see my bin and obj directories in the document root, as well as other likely build artifacts.

Comment: Please provide you RouteConfig file.

Comment: What project type are you using? Are you uploading any build artifacts (like your bin directory)?